# Should I plug or seal my garage floor drain before building a floor on top? (Pests concern)

Tags: garage, drainage

I'm having half my garage turned into office space and building a platform for the floor. Is it ok to plug or seal the existing floor drain? I'm concerned about pests getting inside the new room (there has been a carpenter ant issue around that area in the past)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I would get a solid cover for it.  If for any reason in the future you need the drain(1000 year flood), you will have easy access to it.